# Updating state updates other element's state but not working with localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have developing a react app about blog sites. But at individual blog's like state affecting others. **When i increase the like, other blog's likes increases too.** :( I am using localstorage within `useEffect` but when page reloads, like count returns to initial state -> 10, localstorage keeps increased like count : 11 and when refresh -> goes to initial like : 10. In short state is updating at client side but not at localstorage and at page refresh it turns back to initial state.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router";
import useFetch from "../useFetch";
// FIXME: state changes spreads all of elements
const BlogDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { data: blog } = useFetch(`http://localhost:8000/blogs/${id}`)
  const [likes, setLikes] = useState(10);
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    localStorage.setItem('likes', likes);
    setLikes(likes => likes + 1);
    e.target.setAttribute('disabled', true)
  }
  return (
    <div className="blog-details">
      <h3><b>{blog.title}</b></h3>
      <p>{blog.content}</p>
      <small><em><p>Author: {blog.author}</p></em></small>
      <small><p className="likes">Likes: {localStorage.getItem('likes')}</p></small>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Like</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BlogDetails;
```

Comment: why don't you make likes an key value pair array and inject userId to the array to make it only pull likes specific to the user where userId = x

Comment: This happens because even though the blog IDs are different, all of your blog posts use the SAME `BlogDetails` component. Therefore, all the blog posts actually share the same state. One solution would be, instead of having `likes` being a simple number, set up `likes` to be an object, with specific blog's `id` mapping to the that individual blog's like count. Or you can store the blog post's like count into the database also

Comment: how can i do this ? :( when i use localstorage within useeffect but when page refresh like returns to initial state -> 10, localstorage keeps increased like count : 11 and refresh -> goes to initial like : 10

Comment: @BaoHuynhLam are you mention like this: 
const [likes, setLikes] = useState({
    likes: 10,
    blogID: id
  }); 
--------
setLikes(likes => ({ ...likes, likes+ 1}));
so i can not figure this out. please help

Answer (score 0):

This happens because even though the blog IDs are different, all of your blog posts use the SAME `BlogDetails` component. Therefore, all the blog posts actually share the same state. One solution would be, instead of having `likes` being a simple number, set up `likes` to be an object, with specific blog's id mapping to the that individual blog's like count. Or you can store the blog post's like count into the database also

```
const allBlogIds = ["dragon", "mountain", "pikachu"]; // You add more depending on your blog
const initialLikes = {};
// Set up `initialLikes`
allBlogIds.forEach((id) => {
  initialLikes[id] = 0;
});
// Now `intialLikes` will look like {"dragon": 0, "mountain": 0, "pikachu": 0}

const BlogDetails = (props) => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { data: blog } = useFetch(`http://localhost:8000/blogs/${id}`);
  const [likes, setLikes] = useState(initialLikes); // `likes` is an object
  // Get the like count of this specific blog post
  const likeCount = likes[id];

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    setLikes((old) => ({ ...old, id: old[id] + 1 }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Blog post's specific like count: {likeCount}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>increase count for this blog post only</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Keeping state like this is quite cumbersome as you can see, so it is recommended that you save the like count data to your database (not local storage) also, and query/fetch these data whenever needed

Comment: how can i do this with localstorage @BaoHuynhLam

Comment: You should make a new question for that; I am not too well versed with local storage